# Yii Login Issues

Tags: php, html, yii, modal-dialog, cmenu

My Current Navigation code is as follows

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right nav'),
    'submenuHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown-menu'),
    'itemCssClass'=>'item-test',
    'encodeLabel'=>false,
    'items'=>array(

      array('label'=>'Create Account', 'url'=>array('/site/Register'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),




      array('label'=>'Login','url'=>"#loginModal", 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
      array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
      ),
      )); ?>
```

renders the following in HTML

```
<ul class="pull-right nav" id="yw1">
    <li class="item-test"><a href="/boatapp/site/Register">Create Account</a></li>
    <li class="item-test"><a href="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Now I want to just insert  data-toggle="modal" in the login link.. how do I generate HTML as below>

```
<ul class="pull-right nav" id="yw1">
    <li class="item-test"><a href="/boatapp/site/Register">Create Account</a></li>
    <li class="item-test"><a **data-toggel="modal"** href="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
array('label'=>'Login','url'=>"#loginModal", 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'linkOptions' => array('data-toggle'=>'modal')),
```